# Issue with "viewWithTag"

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to change an iamge of a UIImageView, for that, i'm getting the UIImageView with viewWithTag, i have a crash with message **"-[UIView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9161390"**

I know i have to cast the object, and i already do that:

```
UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView *)[self.view viewWithTag:[[data objectForKey:@"tag"] intValue]];

[iv performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(setImage:) withObject:img waitUntilDone:YES];
```

(i'm using performSelectorOnMainThread because is a background thread, but already try "iv.image = ...").

I'm getting the same error.

Anyone can see what i'm missing?

Thnks!

Edited:

Well thanks for the (really quick!) answers. I can fix it.

I'm was using:

```
[self.view viewWithTag:[[data objectForKey:@"tag"] intValue]]
```

But the UIImageView was in a ScrollView and not un the main view, so using:

```
[scroll viewWithTag:[[data objectForKey:@"tag"] intValue]]
```

instead, fix it.

(Even though cant actually set the image, but i'm not getting the crash).

Thanks Again!

Comment: "I know i have to cast the object, and i already do that" -> that's surely the problem. Is self the instance of your view controller?

Comment: can you elaborate your code then i can help you? may be issue of UIView and UIImageView.

Comment: The view you are getting back is definitely a UIView. Casting just shuts the compiler up. You need to show us the code when you set the tag.

Comment: You don't have to cast the object, btw. Casting is just for making the compiler happy. It doesn't magically make the object respond to selectors it doesn't respond to...

Comment: Also, this is completely unrelated to Xcode.

Comment: see i have shared same thing in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first need to check that the value you are getting is type UIImageView Class. There may be issue of retrieving value from data dictionary or array.May be it is in subview of tableView or ScrollView , then you need take instead of self.view. It may be a different. So You need to debug your code using break point. If this thing goes write then Check for `setImage` method's argument you are passing. Please elaborate your method then i can answer briefly.

Here you are passing two argument with `setImage`.

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You are likely requesting a "value for key" from data that isn't a tag. I would advise against using object value for key because it opens the doors for so many mysterious problems like this to occur.

This goes with what others have posted in your comments: the code you have posted is extremely vague, and because you are using `objectForKey` without showing what `data` is, it's a guessing game of what the problem is.